# How can i choose an exact character in a txt file?

Tags: text-editing

I use Search and Replace software, I need to erase a "-" character in many txt files.
The "-" always appears between two numbers but the numbers are always different (f.e: 1234567-8 or 34569-0).
there are other "-" that appears in the txt file but between letters, not numbers.
if I use [0-9]-[0-9] it chooses the "-" but erases the number before and after the "-" character. 
is there a way to make the software to choose only the "-"I need?

questioner is fine with Notepad++ as text editor.

Comment: What text editor are you using, and are you willing to switch to a different one if yours does not support certain features?

Comment: Without telling us which text editor you're using, your question will be closed as too broad (this is true despite the fact you have received an answer you like). Please do not respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator judging by his answer, he's obviously fine with notepad++

Comment: @barlop I don't feel comfortable editing that into his question. It feels a bit like putting words in his mouth.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Well I just did. I could have done it as a note, it doesn't matter. I think it's preferable to the question being closed because which text editor wasn't mentioned when we know he's fine with a specific one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookahead and lookbehind.  `(?<=[\d])-(?=\d)`

e.g. screenshot from notepad++

[image]

Be sure to tick the regular expression option

[image]

You can even replace `-` or whatever character, with the unicode code for it e.g. `-` is `002D` which I see can be done in notepad++ as `\x{002D}` `(?<=[\d])\x{002D}(?=\d)`

Comment: @TimSelitsky If you no longer need help, please press the check box to mark this question as solved, so others know you no longer need help. :)

Comment: @LPChip it's not a help site, where one marks a question as solved when it is answered. It's a QnA site and one where one doesn't mark a question as solved, but marks an answer as the solution if one decides that it answers the question.   If the answer given answers it, which it does, then he should mark it as the answer.  And f somebody finds another way to do it that is very good then one may post that anwer regardless of whether the person still needs help.

Comment: :@LPChip Just like, if  a person posts a question then gives up, one might post an answer years later, after the person no longer needs help., because it's not a site to help the person that posts the question. It's a QnA site to help anybody looking for answer(s) to the question that was posted.